# Powershell first letter of words

Tags: windows, powershell

If I have a file containing any text, how can I print only the first letter of each word from a file and then print all vowels in capital letters?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried to do so but failed and researched alot. I selected some random text and put it in a text file now wants to print first letter of each word but cant.    $poem = "It's strange how a few short seconds can lead you in a whole new direction,
It alters how you think and act and see your own reflection.
From a single moment on, my life was forever changed,
Like everything I previously knew had suddenly been rearranged.



$poem | Out-file "C:\users\Poem.txt"      . This is the file and I want to print first letter of each word.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be a little tricky for a PowerShell starter.

```
$poem = Get-Content "C:\somewhere\poem.txt"
$x = (($poem.Split(' ') | % { $_[0] }) -join "").ToUpper()
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\xy> $x
ISHAFSSCLYIAWNDIAHYTAAASYORFASMOMLWFCLEIPKHSBR
```

explanation:

- `$poem.split(" ")` breaks the whole `$poem` string on each leash and creates an object for each word.
- `| %` alias `ForEach` takes every object and executes the scriptblock `{}` for each object.
- `$_[0]` selects the first letter of the current object

This would now return an array of objects, instead of one simple string.

- `-join ""` puts those objects together to a string. the value inside `""` defines what's written between each object, in our case nothing.
- `.ToUpper()` is a method for strings which will make every letter to a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented, but still not enaugh rep.
The Vowel part was missing. I thaught first of an array -contains, but a -cmatch is easier. That same poem returns here:

```
$poem = Get-Content ".\cwItc.txt"
$x = (($poem.Split(' ') | % {
  If ($_[0] -cmatch "[aeiou]") {$_[0].ToUpper} else {$_[0]}
} ) -join "" )
$x

> .\FirstLetterVow2up.ps1
IshfssclywndIhytsyrFsmmlwfcLIpkhsbrNwjhIftdBdwtpIsttcIcbttrpIkItsthtIwtIwpt
whrcsAtAMwnswltdSIwcnpwtWIdwtmfIttfbmwhhbIwlcthtppMmfwchfwlHtpmwtTlpgddmfIp
hswfldHctlvstlmHwwbhwhmpSttnsssIwcbvdlsprTgmldmptmbsIctsscbwrsfWttdhmwfdHwd
wvcIbftpshbAttthdlmSlnIscfsThmnlmtkWsctwpnImgrtcbnrImhtssgbmncBIktttdshwImh
tpthsmttsAhcmdttcImhtkhbtcwcIhftwptglIcctptwIsBIcftpcwtcWsdysmtsEswwkpEhttw
ntrIlsrmfStllftkDdwsbmtbTddnjtrFwdhtwwcrtbSh
```

Comment: oh i missed that "vowel" part. thx for correction.